# What is the point of google.protobuf.StringValue?

Tags: protocol-buffers

I've recently encountered all sorts of wrappers in Google's `protobuf` package.  I'm struggling to imagine the use case.  Can anyone shed the light: what problem were these intended to solve?

Here's one of the documentation links: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/csharp/class/google/protobuf/well-known-types/string-value (it says nothing about what can this be used for).

One thing that will be different in behavior between this, and simple `string` type is that this field will be written less efficiently (a couple extra bytes, plus a redundant memory allocation).  For other wrappers, the story is even worse, since the `repeated` variants of those fields will be written inefficiently (official Google's Protobuf serializer doesn't support `packed` encoding for non-numeric types).

Neither seems to be desirable.  So, what's this all about?

Comment: The keyword seems to be "well known types", but I still don't really know their purpose: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/protobuf/9YK-kyNFe-E

Comment: @jpa Ah, OK, I think I understand now where this is coming from... Protobuf on the wire level doesn't require that any fields be present, but it also allows specifying default values. Now, it is possible to deserialize zero bytes into a whole bunch of objects... but you will never know if you actually received anything, or just pretending to receive. So, having wrappers, makes it possible to tell whether you actually received anything because default will be different.

Comment: It was suggested to me by coworkers that StringValue's default is empty, whereas string's default is the empty string. So StringValue can represent one additional situation as compared to string.

Answer (score 49):

There's a few reasons, mostly to do with where these are used - see [struct.proto](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/master/src/google/protobuf/struct.proto).

`StringValue` can be null, `string` often can't be in a language interfacing with protobufs. e.g. in Go strings are always set; the "zero value" for a string is "", the empty string, so it's impossible to distinguish between "this value is intentionally set to empty string" and "there was no value present". `StringValue` can be null and so solves this problem. It's especially important when they're used in a `StructValue`, which may represent arbitrary JSON: to do so it needs to distinguish between a JSON key which was set to empty string (`StringValue` with an empty string) or a JSON key which wasn't set at all (null `StringValue`).

Also if you look at struct.proto, you'll see that these aren't fully fledged message types in the proto - they're all generated from `message Value`, which has a `oneof kind { number_value, string_value, bool_value...` etc. By using a `oneof` struct.proto can represent a variety of different values in one field. Again this makes sense considering what struct.proto is designed to handle - arbitrary JSON - you don't know what type of value a given JSON key has ahead of time.

Comment: `StringValue` could be not set. On the recipient side, `StringValue` has `.has*`(e.g. `.hasUserId()` methods which could be used instead of null check. In that way you can avoid passing some primitive values. But don't try to set `null` into `StringValue` field.

Answer (score 7):

In addition to George's answer, you can't use a Protobuf primitive as the parameter or return value of a gRPC procedure.

Comment: Your statement seems to not match the following documentation - perhaps the answer is outdated: https://grpc.io/docs/what-is-grpc/introduction/

Comment: @AminAriana the answer is not outdated. I can't see anything in the documentation that contradicts it.

Comment: I see this sentence which may be interpreted as the answer, so you're right: "You define gRPC services in ordinary proto files, with RPC method parameters and return types specified as protocol buffer messages"